# How to keep only this specific part of url?

Tags: php

http://www.example.com/hu/link

Using PHP how can I only keep the `hu`? Please note that the `link` is only one variable, it may be anything

Comment: This isn't clear - are you talking about parsing the url to extract the path segments? Or a redirect of some kind?

Comment: @Bulk Yes, parsing it to the path segments. Basically I want to echo the `hu` or any other between the `.com/.../`

Comment: Use `explode()` to split the URL on the `/` characters, then take the 2nd-to-last element of the array.

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos This could help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$exploded = explode('/', 'http://www.example.com/hu/link');
$value = $exploded[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is this:

```
$split = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
echo $split[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/hu/link";

$split_url = explode('/', $url);
echo $split_url[3];
```

Output:

```
hu
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regular expression [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) like this:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/hu/link';
preg_match('/.*www.*\/(.*)\//i',$url, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: The reason I downvoted. **1)** There is a parse error. **2)** What if the URL doesn't include the www.? There will be no match. **3)** It's "over-engineering" when you can just `explode()`, albeit a nice alternative.